# Extract Values based on Keys in a Bigquery column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have data in the form of key value pair (Not Json) as shown below

```
id | Attributes
---|---------------------------------------------------
12 | Country:US, Eligibility:Yes, startDate:2022-08-04
33 | Country:CA, Eligibility:Yes, startDate:2021-12-01
11 | Country:IN, Eligibility:No, startDate:2019-11-07
```

I would like to extract only startDate from Attributes section

Expected Output:

```
id | Attributes_startDate
---|----------------------
12 | 2022-08-04
33 | 2021-12-01
11 | 2019-11-07
```

One way that I tried was, I tired converting the Attributes column in the Input data into JSON by appending {, } at start and end positions respectively. Also some how tried adding double quotes on the Key values and tried extracting startDate. But, is there any other effective solution to extract startDate as I don't want to rely on Regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to just specify the key and extract its respective value? (Just like the way we can extract values using keys in a JSON column using JSON_QUERY)

you can try below

```
create temp function fakejson_extract(json string, attribute string) as ((
  select split(kv, ':')[safe_offset(1)] 
  from unnest(split(json)) kv
  where trim(split(kv, ':')[offset(0)]) = attribute
));
select id, 
  fakejson_extract(Attributes, 'Country') as Country,
  fakejson_extract(Attributes, 'Eligibility') as Eligibility,
  fakejson_extract(Attributes, 'startDate') as startDate
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in  your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> is there any other effective solution to extract startDate as I don't want to rely on Regex.

If your feeling about Regex here really very strong  - use below

```
select id, split(Attribute, ':')[safe_offset(1)] Attributes_startDate
from your_table, unnest(split(Attributes)) Attribute
where trim(split(Attribute, ':')[offset(0)]) = 'startDate'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below (I think using RegEx here is the most efficient option)

```
select id, regexp_extract(Attributes, r'startDate:(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})') Attributes_startDate
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. Tried somewhat a similar approach.  I know I mentioned that I want to extract startDate alone in my question,But is there a way to make it dynamic, like - What if I want to extract Country or Eligibility or any other new attribute in futrue. I might have different attributes in different columns. Is there any way to just specify the key and extract its respective value? (Just like the way we can extract values using keys in a JSON column using JSON_QUERY)